# Hanging install blocks new installations on WebOS

Tags: software-installation, webos

I tried to install an application via AppScoop. From that point on no further installs were possible because of a hanging install (see picture). Can you please advice how to cancel the hanging install? I have shell access so don't mind sending shell commands.

[image: Hanging Software Installation]